# Horizontal line for start and end date for each factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe

```
ses <- data.frame("Sport"=c("NBA", "NFL", "MLB", "NHL"), 
                  "reg_ses_start"=(as.Date(c("2016-10-25", "2016-09-08", "2016-04-03", "2016-10-12"))),
                  "reg_ses_end"=as.Date(c("2017-04-12","2017-01-01", "2016-11-02", "2017-04-09" )))
```

I would like to show start and end date for each sport with a horizontal line. I would like to use ggplot for this but cant really see how I can add two point on x-axis.

Comment: And what have you tried? Do you have some plot without the horizontal line? Are you aware of [this](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_abline.html) help page?

Answer (score 3):

Do you want something like this (change the x/y axis label if you need)?

```
library(scales)
ses$SportID <- 1:4
ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data = ses, aes(x = reg_ses_start, y = SportID, xend = reg_ses_end, yend = SportID, col= Sport), size = 2)+
  scale_x_date( breaks=date_breaks("5 days")) + 
  xlab('Time') + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I first use `as.POSIXct` to format the date:

```
ses <- data.frame(Sport = ses$Sport,
             start = as.POSIXct(ses$reg_ses_start, format="%Y-%m-%d"), 
             end = as.POSIXct(ses$reg_ses_end, format="%Y-%m-%d"))
```

You can use the `geom_rect` for this

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_rect(data=ses, aes(xmin=start, xmax=end,
                              ymin=Sport, ymax=Sport, color=Sport),size=10)
```

[image]